# How to extract matrix together with vocab from gensim word2vec model

Tags: python, extract, gensim, word2vec

I've trained a word2vec model like so

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# create model without initializing
model = Word2Vec(min_count=20,
                 window=5,
                 sample=6e-5, 
                 negative=20,
                 workers=cores-1,
                 vector_size=300)

# build vocabulary
w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences, progress_per=10000)

# train model
model.train(sentences, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=30, report_delay=1)
```

I'd like to export the model as a dataframe, but not sure how to extract the matrix and vocab together correctly, with the right index positions.

Something like this:

| label | V1 | V2 | V... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| government | 0.560774564 | -0.0464625023 | ... |
| state | 0.0106112240 | 0.0464625023 | ... |
| .... | ... | .. | . |

I've tried this:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(model.syn1neg)
tmp.insert(0, 'label', model.wv.index_to_key)
```

which does not square up when comparing

```
>>> model.wv.get_index('government')
10
>>> tmp.loc[[0]]
0 government 0.329972  0.160003 -0.516633  ...  0.460873 -0.170273 -1.621128  1.255289
```

Comment: Note that DataFrames are very inefficient for storing the raw vectors. Still, if that's what you want, are you aiming to have individual vectors (as Python numpy objects) as one column, or every dimension in its own column (300 dim cols)? (Separately: the peculiar `alpha` & `min_alpha` values you're using are usually a hint you're following a bad online tutorial. There's no reason to suspect those arbitrary values any better than usual defaults. And, if you were looking to optimize those values properly, it's unlikely you'd wind up at those values, especially the bizarre `min_alpha=0.0007`.)

Comment: @gojomo Aiming for every dimension in its own column with the related word. Thanks for pointing out `alpha` & `min_alpha`, I'll just use the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this with gensim 4.x.x here's what I wound up doing:

```
vocab, vectors = model.wv.key_to_index, model.wv.vectors

# get label and vector index.
label_index = np.array([(voc[0], voc[1]) for voc in vocab.items()])

# init dataframe using embedding vectors and set index as node name
tmp =  pd.DataFrame(vectors[label_index[:,1].astype(int)])
tmp.index = label_index[:, 0]
tmp.to_csv("matrix_with_labels.csv")
```

Not sure this is the best or proper way but it works.

Comment: Glad you got over the block - whatever creates the format you need should be fine. But I would again emphasize that expanding the typical 'native' (& compact) `numpy` arrays that usually hold these values into a dataframe where every dimension has its own column is *inefficient* and *atypical*. And further, since a "dense embedding" like word2vec word-vectors generally doesn't result in dimensions that are individually interpretable, trying this might indicate you're proceeding down an unwise path.

Comment: (That is, you generally can't say of dense embeddings that "dimension #77 means X" for any meaningful X. To the extent vague neighborhoods, and directions, in the full 30-dimension space, might map to human-describable concepts, those don't neatly align to single dimensions, but rather 'shear' across all dimensions in ways that are especially tricky for typical human directional intuitions, optimized for 2-3 dimensions, easily understand.)

Comment: (er, "300-dimensional" space. SO oughtta allow comment edits for longer than a measly 5 minutes!)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and thanks for the comments. The reason I want to export the matrix is to use it in with this [R package](https://github.com/prodriguezsosa/conText) in order to do embedding regression etc. Haven't found anything similar, and I don't have the Python knowledge to implement it.

Comment: @gojomo Do you know of a better way for exporting the output of gensim `Word2Vec` model for that use case?

Comment: If that package reads in GLoVe embeddings, you may just be able to save any Gensim `KeyedVectors` to a compatible on-disk format. (It's not exactly clear in that package's quick-start guide how the pretrained `cr_glove_subset` is initialized.) I think the usual format of GLoVe embeddings is just the same as what Gensim's `.save_word2vec_format()` method will write, if you use the non-default `write_header=False` option.